# best CAPTCHA framework for gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, frameworks, captcha

i  need a CAPTCHA  framework on google-app-engine

what a CAPTCHA  framework you are using .

thanks

like this :http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html

Comment: what's wrong with recaptcha? http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-recaptcha-with-google-app-engine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/) is nice. Heres a [tutorial](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-recaptcha-with-google-app-engine.html) on how to make it work in google app engine.